# php interacting with running c++

Tags: php, c++

There are quite a lot of questions that have been asked about this issue, but some of them are quite old and their references are gone... And there seems to be quite a lot of possible answer and I want to make sure I understand properly.

I have a c++ program that does a lot of complex things. I would like to have this c++ program running permanently on the server and interact with my php web application.

The solutions I have found are :

```
- using named pipes
- creating a php extension
- using SWIG
- use sockets
- Write a C++ listener that recognizes XML RPC or SOAP requests
```

What do you think about those solution. Is one way simpler to the others for a complex c++ program as I have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on kind of interaction. The most performant way is a pipe or unix socket (within a single system). The most comfortable for PHP developer is XML RPC or SOAP.